# python audiotools hanging at get_metadata()

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to read metadata of this file

```
http://wormtune.com/test/1.mp3
```

using python 2.7 and audiotools 2.19.

```
import audiotools
a = audiotools.open('/tmp/1.mp3')
a.get_metadata() # <-- dead hanging
```

python is using 100% of cpu and doing nothing...
What is going on? How to prevent hanging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work. I have two files in local(one is flac, another is mp3) and they can print the metadata. But when I tried your file, it raises an error 'UnsupportedFile'.

Maybe you can have a try except block to avoid a blocking.

I am using the latest audiotools and python 2.7.